# MFC - Creating a child view of CSplitterWnd fails

Tags: c++, mfc

Good evening,

I am stuck on a really strange problem.
I have a CSplitterWnd object and I want to add two child pane to it.
The two pane are from two subclass of the CFormView class.

I add them with the following code :
(Please note that this code is called in the OnCreateClient function of the CMainFrame class)

```
BOOL result = SplitWindow.CreateStatic(this, 1, 2);

if (!result) 
    return FALSE;

CRect cRect;
GetClientRect(&cRect);

int iHeight = theApp.GetProfile().ImageHeight ? theApp.GetProfile().ImageWidth : cRect.Height() / 2;
CSize szSize1(cRect.Width() / 2, iHeight);

if (!SplitWindow.CreateView(0, 0, RUNTIME_CLASS(CView1), szSize1, pContext))
{
    SplitWindow.DestroyWindow();
    return FALSE;
}

CSize szSize2(cRect.Width() / 2, iHeight);

if (!SplitWindow.CreateView(0, 1, RUNTIME_CLASS(CView2), szSize2, pContext))
{
    SplitWindow.DestroyWindow();
    return FALSE;
}
```

The CView1 and CView2 class are two class derived from a class CBaseView class which itself is a child of CFormView (I use only one dialog definition in CBaseView).

The problem I am facing is that the call to "CreateView" always returns FALSE.
I went inside the MFC code and found out a strange thing that is shown in the following image :

[image]

In the CreateView function of CSplitterWnd class, I see that a check to the pWnd pointer address is failing despite the pointer not being NULL.
I am using debug compilation with all optimizations disabled so what I see in the debugger should be true, right ?

Is there someone that would know about this ?
My main purpose is to be able to create those sub-views.

I have to add that at first it was working, then I added the class CBaseView and derivated the CView1 and CView2 from CBaseView.
When it was working CView1 and CView2 were at that time children of CFormView.
I tried to go back to this configuration, but I saw exactly the same problem as I have now.

Hope someone could help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am adding also that I get the following comments in the Output window :Warning: Creating a pane with no CDocument.
Warning: couldn't create client pane for splitter.

Comment: When you changed the class hierarchy did you change *all* of the base class references in the MFC macros like `IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE` and `BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP`?

Comment: Hi Roger, thank you for your comment. Yes I did check it. I double-checked after reading your comments and everything is fine regarding this. Also, I just made another project with exactly the same code for the views creation (splitter, base view and two sub-view) and it works in this solution. Something around that may cause the trouble but so far the debugger couldn't give me a clue.

Comment: Ok if a new solution with the same code is working fine, it must be need a Rebuild on the failing solution - that's always my first action for any weird errors....

Comment: Did it :) Cleaned solution first (not working), then deleted by hand all Debug folders. Not working. Also disabled the "use precompiled headers". Not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
It was due to the resource dialog linked to the CBaseView.
It contains MFCRangeSlider resource that was not yet handled. Deleting this resource or handling it properly is enough to succeed in creating the child views.